# Python : update value in nested dictonary after reading keys from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I need to update the value in dictionary after reading the keys from list.
e.g.

> d1 =
>   {"sun":{"mon":"111"},"tue":{"wed":"222"},"thu":{"fri":{"sat":"333"}}}
>   and l1 = ["thu","fri","sat"].

Here I need to change the value of`d1["thu"]["fri"]["sat"]` to `444`.

Please tell me how can I write a function which takes `d1`, `l1` and new value as parameters and returns the updated dictionary.

Comment: Please show us how tried to approach the problem and why you think your solution didn't work.

Comment: what's the relationship of `l1` to `d1`? why would `l1` need to be included in a function used to update `d1` if you already have the new value parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create a new dict and use it to update the original one

```
def create_update_dict(keys, val):
    if len(keys) == 1:
        return {keys[0]: val}
    else:
        return {keys[0]: create_update_dict(keys[1:], val)}

def update_dict_val(d, val, keys):
    update_dict = create_update_dict(keys, val)
    d.update(update_dict)
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last dict(which you want update) and update its value. Using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function its pretty simple

```
from functools import reduce

def update_dict(nested_dict, key, value):
    last_dict = reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], key[:-1], nested_dict)
    last_dict[key[-1]] = value
```

Ouput:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}
>>> update_dict(d, ['a', 'b'], 2)
>>> d
{'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 2}}
```